# why copyfield can not use PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory in solr

Tags: solr, hbase, cloudera-cdh

my solr cloud version is 4.10.3 in coudera cdh5.4.7.I want to use copyfield to copy hbase rowkey to another field and use PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory to delete some pattern.But it doesn't work.When i search document,the rowkey_column and rowkey is the same,not cut anything.For example,rowkey is

```
"HDSA00_01$41872607-9_11654094_1001292270_1443404975000$0"
```

,and rowkey_column must be

```
"41872607-9_11654094_1001292270_1443404975000$0"
```

.But i get the same with rowkey.Why?please help me!

```
My config in schema.xml is here,rowkey is a string type:
```

```
<field name="rowkey_column" type="rowkeyColumn" indexed="true" stored="true" />  
<copyField source="rowkey" dest="rowkey_column"/>
<fieldType name="rowkeyColumn" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="^\S{9}\$|^HealthArchives\$"   maxBlockChars="20000"  />
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want `$` there, since it means "end of string", meaning that the only thing that will be matched is anything that's not whitespace, and exactly nine characters long. You also want to add `replacement=""` to say that it should be removed.

You can also use the "Analysis" page under the admin page (at least for native Solr, I guess Cloudera has the same functionality available) to see exactly how the text is processed for each step in your analysis chain for the field.

copyField shouldn't be relevant for this, since copyField directives happen long before any field definitions are invoked.

Comment: replacement=“” is not a default？

Comment: i use the follow answer myself: <fieldType name="rowkeyColumn" class="solr.TextField">
       <analyzer>
          <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\w+\$)(\d+\-.*)"  replacement="$2"   />
          <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
    </fieldType>